# html elements having style float:left

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#009;
}
#container_left{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#960;
}
#container_right{
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#909;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sample Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container_left">
    left div
</div>
<div id="container_right">
    right div
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I had expected the div with id wrapper to have the height of its contents, but the wrapper div seems to have disappeared from the body, since the `background-color` is not working finely for it.

It reappears when I remove `float:left` from inner div elements, but this solution isn't correct for the overall design.

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of element with float CAN float out of the box of parent element

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="container_left">
left div
</div>
<div id="container_right">
right div
</div>
<div style="clear:both; overflow:hidden; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

You must put element with clear style to the end of parent content - it will be placed under both floated divs AND will not float out of the box (So parent div will be resized to disered size )

Other solution is to set height for parent div

Comment: Thanks dude,this works for me,Great.Giving height for a dynamic site not a solution,Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

When content inside a div is floating the height cannot be calculated unless the property height, overflow: auto or display: inline-block is present on the parent div

Comment: thanks man ,great.overflow: auto works for me,but display: inline-block  not works for me